# how to use the startActivity in a class that extends a view?

Tags: java, android, sudoku

I have a Class PuzzleView that extends View. I want to be able to open a new activity Congratulations from this View when an if statement returns true.

```
public class PuzzleView extends View { 
/*Code here blah blah blah then*/
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
  if (game.isSolved()== true)
  {
    Context context = getContext();
    Intent i = new Intent(PuzzleView.this, Congratulations.class);
    getContext().startActivity(i);
  }
```

The error I am getting is "The constructor Intent(PuzzleView, Class) is undefined" here

```
new Intent(PuzzleView.this, Congratulations.class);
```

In reply to @imrankhan here is the whole onKeyDown()

```
@Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
   {

       if (game.isSolved()== true)
       {
           Context context = getContext();
           Intent i = new Intent(context, Congratulations.class);
           context.startActivity(i);
       }
       else
       {
      Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: keycode=" + keyCode + ", event="
            + event);
      switch (keyCode) {
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
         select(selX, selY - 1);
         break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
         select(selX, selY + 1);
         break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
         select(selX - 1, selY);
         break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
         select(selX + 1, selY);
         break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE: setSelectedTile(0); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:     setSelectedTile(1); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:     setSelectedTile(2); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:     setSelectedTile(3); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4:     setSelectedTile(4); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5:     setSelectedTile(5); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6:     setSelectedTile(6); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7:     setSelectedTile(7); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8:     setSelectedTile(8); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9:     setSelectedTile(9); break;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
         game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
         break;
      default:
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
      }
      return true;
       }


   }
```

Comment: Why are you getting context and not using it... ?

Comment: @JoxTraex to be honest not 100% sure. I am learning and this was in an example I found

Answer (score 0):

try as

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
  if (game.isSolved()== true)
  {
    Context context = getContext();
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Congratulations.class);
    context.startActivity(i);

  }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Comment: That fixes the first error but then on this line `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) ` i get the error "This method must return a result of type boolean"

Comment: @WillNZ Post your complete code. And, have a look at [`onKeyDown`](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/example-code-for-onkeydown-listener-in.html) example

Comment: @WillNZ : see my edit answer and add a `return true` or` return false` in onKeyDown method

Comment: @imrankhan please see my edit question with the whole onKeyDown method which did not like the return super as there is already one further down the method

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this -

```
Context context = getContext();
Intent i = new Intent(context, Congratulations.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This also has the same error problem that fixes the first error but then on this line `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` i get the error "This method must return a result of type boolean"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass activity reference in Constructor of the view, you can use this reference later. So define a constructor like following:

```
public class PuzzleView extends View
{
    Activity mActivity;
    public PuzzleView(Activity activity, Context context)
    {
         super(context);
         this.mActivity=activity;
    }
}
```

now use this activity reference to start activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, Congratulations.class);
    getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I get the following error "The constructor View() is undefined" on the line `super();`

Comment: Hi jeet "context cannot be resolved to a variable" any ideas?

Comment: "The blank final field game may not have been initialized" on line `public PuzzleView(Activity activity, Context context) ` but I have no idea where to initialise it

Comment: you can initialize it in Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers here. But it looks like they lack information as of why it is not allowed. Let me put it in simple terms.

When you start an Intent, it requires two arguments, one would be the context or an Activity reference and the other would be the next Activity class.

But what you are trying to do is that, you are trying to pass the **this** reference to a class which extends View and which is why you are getting this error.

The context object actually acts as the reference in the stack as of from where the control was transferred. So it is required for you to pass the context object or the Activity object itself along with it.

> Last but not least, Activity is actually extended form Context Class. So either of them will do the task for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep application context in the view class so following code will answer you.

```
 public class PuzzleView extends View { 
    Context mContext;
        public PuzzleView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);  
        mContext=context;// keep the context

        } 
     @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (game.isSolved()== true){
              Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Congratulations.class);
               mcontext.startActivity(i);
      }
```

**EDIT**

Your view should be like this.

```
<com.yourpackage.PuzzleView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/yourid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I get this error "The blank final field game may not have been initialized" on this line `public PuzzleView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {`

Comment: are you using this view in your xml file or you create instance of this view using new keyword on your java file??

Comment: what is varable "game" ?? you have to initialize it on the constructor.

Comment: The view is an xml file called Congratulations which is also added to the Manifest file. Would it help if I showed you the whole java page?